# How to get all unicode characters of a language by using its ISO language code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, linguistics

For example, the ISO language code of German language is `de`.
How do I get all unicode characters of that language in Python?

---

If that's not directly possible, how about the following:
Given an ISO language code (say `de`),

1. How do I find the script name given an ISO language code?

(For example, script used for German is Latin)

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> ud.name('ß')
'LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S'
```

2. Now using this script name, how do I get all the unicode characters of that script?

Comment: Some languages are regularly written using more than one script, either because scripts are interchangeable or because the written language consists of more than one script. (Does that even include Arabic numerals in regular Latin script…?) Is "ï" an "English" character…? You wouldn't usually say so, yet "naïve" can be written using it in regular English. So… this is all rather vaguely defined…

Comment: Even Germans themselves can't agree whether their alphabet consists of 26 letters and 4 "special letters" or 30… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography#Special_letters What problem exactly are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Okay, my use-case is not exactly for the German language. It's a bit more generic. For instance, if you take the language "Hindi", the script it uses is called `Devanagari` and the characters are completed fixed (unlike the German case). So, what I want to solve is, to generate random strings for any given language. For example, if I specify `Simplified Chinese`'s language code, I need to get all the language's characters using which I can generate random strings. It need not cover all the languages of the world, even just the python unicode standardized ones would do.

Comment: Something like https://mimesis.readthedocs.io or https://faker.readthedocs.io…?

Comment: Yes, maybe something like that! But seems like many languages are not yet supported, mainly the ones I'm targeting my app for. And I don't even need a library like that, just the list of alphabets given any language code would be more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

The Unicode CLDR project compiles the information you're looking for (and more besides). For example, in the [CLDR data for 'de' German](https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/37/summary/de.html) (link is to data in the latest release), see the first row in the data. Python makes use of some CLDR data (e.g., for regex patterns by character properties), but probably not this particular data. Look for a library that provides support for CLDR exemplars by language/locale.

[2022-7-29: Additional info]
The CLDR language exemplar data lists characters used for particular languages. That data is exposed in the ICU library (see the [header file](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/ulocdata_8h.html) for relevant APIs). And the [PyICU](https://pypi.org/project/PyICU/) extension for Python wraps the ICU library.

Comment: Thanks! *`Look for a library that provides support for CLDR exemplars by language/locale.`* - Please let me know if any. I didn't find any.

Comment: @GokulNC Just so you know - two years later and you are not alone in not finding anything. Inexplicably there also seems to be animosity in just asking if a package exists or some explicit code.

Comment: @rocky, Gokul NC: I made an inquiry and updated my answer with info that should help.

Comment: @rocky it's not inexplicable. Recommendations go stale quicker than most other answers and so have been discouraged from the earliest days of the site. But code is always welcome.

Comment: @MarkRansom when there are _no_ easily usable solutions mentioned, and after several years goes by, I think most of the people looking for help would prefer _any_  package or piece of code. Something that does what you want I don't consider a recommendation, but a _solution_.  I think of a recommendation is when there are several options. And there has been no concrete code offered either.  It feels to me that people are hiding behind process as a way to cover the fact that in essence this there is currently no satisfactory solution other than go look here and write some code for yourself.

Comment: @MarkRansom go to the search bar and type "Can someone recommend" and you will see numerous posts. This "no recommendation" thing is clearly not something that is followed as a hard and fast kind of thing. I think if you were to try to close all of the thousands of posts that recommend software, you'd find stiff resistance.

To be clear, it is not animosity for asking for recommendations across the board, it is just about recommendations about _this_ particular topic.

Comment: @PeterConstable When I looked earlier and searched PyPI I had come across PYIC, and I have looked again at both that package and the header file you mention. In my particular case, I want the basic lowercase letters that a schoolchild would learn for the alphabet of their language. I don't see an easy way (i.e. something less than 50 lines of code) that gets this from the information in either of those two sources.

Comment: @rocky I was just trying to explain the attitude, I wasn't trying to defend it.  I think a lot of the policies Stack Overflow tries to impose are too drastic.

Comment: @rocky Wouldn't ulocdata_getExemplarSet() combined with u_foldCase() (see https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/uchar_8h.html) do what you need?

Comment: @PeterConstable Thanks! I think that is the function I am looking for. There still is a bit of work to turn this API name into even a complete sample program in Python, but this is definitely what I would use to writing such a thing in the future. (Ironic that on the question side we can't ask for software recommendations, but on the answer side, that is done all of the time).  I am thankful for this information and it solves this for me personally.  However I do hope you realize this kind of answer requires a bit more work on the user side than is needed in the typical SO solution.

Comment: @rocky "Any answer that fully addresses at least part of the question is helpful and can get the asker going in the right direction." (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). I think what I provided is in line with that.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but I will build on Peter Constable's suggestion.

Exemplar data, as well as auxillary characters and punctuation defined in CLDR is available via the `icu.LocaleData` class.

First we initiate a LocaleData object for German. We need to specify a language tag, rather than a locale object for this class:

```py
import icu
de_ld = icu.LocaleData('de-DE')
exemplars = de_ld.getExemplarSet(0, 0)
print(exemplars)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'ß', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü']
```

`icu.LocaleData.getExemplarSet` will return an `icu.UnicodeSet` object. Just convert this to a Python `set` or `list` as required.

And then retrieve the exemplar characters using `icu.LocaleData.getExemplatSet(options, extype)`, where `options` is set to `0` which is the unmodified exemplar set (all lowercase characters, and `extype` is set to `0` or `icu.ULocaleDataExemplarSetType.ES_STANDARD`.

We can also sort them, using Standard German collation rules:

```py
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('de_DE'))
exemplars.sort(key=collator.getSortKey)
print(exemplars)
# ['a', 'ä', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'ö', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'ß', 't', 'u', 'ü', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

But the language tag is important. This list created for Standard German, will differ from the list for Swiss Standard German.

In Unicode Set notation:

Standard German:[a-zßäöü]
Swiss Standard German: [a-zäöü]

If we set options to `4` or `icu.USET_ADD_CASE_MAPPINGS`, we get a version of the exemplar set with add additional case mappings:

```py
exemplars_full = de_ld.getExemplarSet(icu.USET_ADD_CASE_MAPPINGS, icu.ULocaleDataExemplarSetType.ES_STANDARD)
print(exemplars_full)
```

Which returns the Unicode set: [A-Za-zÄÖÜßäöü{SS}{Ss}{ss}]