# Is there a python equivalent of ['A'..'Z'] in turbo pascal

Tags: python, slice, turbo-pascal

Like the topic, is there a (quick) way, possibly a notation, to achieve the same effect as in turbo pascal to rapid make a list of all elements containing and between 'A' and 'Z'.

In turbo pascal it could be written as ['A'..'Z']

Comment: Hmm, off the top of my head, there's `[chr(x) for x in range(b'A'[0], b'Z'[0])]
` but there's got to be something more elegant than that.... ` [chr(x) for x in range(ord('A'), ord('Z'))]` is slightly more readable...

Comment: However, depending on what your use case is, there may be different solutions, like using a regular expression.  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: A solution for that exact list, but completely not generic, is `list(string.ascii_uppercase)`. Depends really whether you're looking for that precise list, or using it as an example of a more generic requirement.

Comment: @max Use case is to write my code a little bit eleganter, suddenly I remembered in TP there was an elegant way to write those things, so I wondered what the most elegant/pythonic way is to write those things.

Comment: A lot depends on what you want to do next. Iterate through the list? Check membership?

Comment: Python doesn't have a char type - `'A'` and so on are just strings of length 1 - so it doesn't lend itself to doing this so concisely.

Comment: @DYZ check if the first char of a variable is in the list. So I can run two independent programs to spread load, or spread network load (different ip adresses) depending on the first char of a specific var. For example program 1 : ['A'..'D'] program 2 : ['E'..'Z'] etc

Comment: You could just compare strings: `if 'A' <= some_string[0] <= 'D':` for example. And you can do that without needing to materialize all the intermediate letters into a collection.

Comment: @slothrop : good point ! most of the time I did something like if some_string[0] in ['A'..'F'] etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map on a range of character numbers:

```
*letters, = map(chr,range(65,91)) # A-Z

print(letters)

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

You can combine multiple ranges using unpacking:

```
*alphanum, = *map(chr,range(65,91)), *"0123456789", *map(chr,range(97,122))
```

Alternatively you could create a shorthand function of you own:

```
def CHR(a,*b):
    return [*map(chr,range(ord(a[0]),ord(a[-1])+1))] + (CHR(*b) if b else [])
```

Which you can reuse as needed:

```
codeChars = CHR('A..Z','-','0..9')

print(codeChars)

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
 'Y', 'Z', '-', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
 '9']
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the most elegant, simple and pythonic way is to use `string` module:

```py
import string
print(string.ascii_uppercase)
>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
x = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
print(x)
>>> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

---

EDIT: if you need alphabet for languages containing non-ASCII or even non-Latin characters you can use [`PyICU`](https://pypi.org/project/PyICU) (here's a guide how to install for Windows users: https://github.com/cgohlke/pyicu-build). Then, you are able to run this script:

```py
# imports
import locale

from icu import Collator, Locale, LocaleData

# official language name
locale_language, encoding = locale.getlocale()

# alphabet lowercase
locale_alphabet: list = list(LocaleData(locale_language).getExemplarSet())

# alphabet uppercase
locale_alphabet_uppercase: list = list(map(str.upper, locale_alphabet))

# output
print(locale_alphabet_uppercase)
```

The thing is `PyICU` generates unsorted list of characters (in my case - for Polish):

```py
>>> ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'Y', 'Z', 'Ó', 'Ą', 'Ć', 'Ę', 'Ł', 'Ń', 'Ś', 'Ź', 'Ż']
```

To correctly sort letters according to your language standard, you can specify custom sorting key using `Collator` from `PyICU` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11124645/11485896):

```py
# sorting
collator = Collator.createInstance(Locale(locale_language))

# output
print(sorted(locale_alphabet_uppercase, key = collator.getSortKey))
```

Output:

```py
>>> ['A', 'Ą', 'B', 'C', 'Ć', 'D', 'E', 'Ę', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Ł', 'M', 'N', 'Ń', 'O', 'Ó', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'Ś', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'Y', 'Z', 'Ź', 'Ż']
```

Comment: If you want both upper and lowercase, an alternative approach is `locale_alphabet: list = list(LocaleData(locale_language).getExemplarSet(4, 0))`

Comment: alternatively, since you uppercased all the letters, the index characters for the locale may be more suitable: `locale_alphabet: list = list(LocaleData(locale_language).getExemplarSet(0, 2))`

Comment: you could also use set operations to remove all Basic Latin characters and get a list of extended Latin characters used for the target language

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no other way to do this in Python that's as compact and elegant. As @Soren said, for letters, you can use `string.ascii_uppercase` or `string.ascii_lowercase`, on which you can do slicing. For instance, `print(string.ascii_uppercase[3:7])` prints "DEFG".

If you want something more generic, more readable, and not limited to latin alphabet letters, you have to write a class to approach what you want.
I wrote this very simple example as a proof of concept (it misses many little details). It should work with any iterable (even though I've only tested it with strings).

```py
class Slicer:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content
    
    def __getitem__(self, key: slice):
        if key.step is not None:
            return self.content[self.content.index(key.start) : self.content.index(key.stop)+1 : key.step]
        return self.content[self.content.index(key.start) : self.content.index(key.stop)+1]
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Slicer({self.content!r})"

import string
letters = Slicer(string.ascii_uppercase)
print(letters)
# Slicer('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
print(letters["A":"H"])
# ABCDEFGH
print(letters["A":"H":2])
# ACEG
```

If you want to dig further, it uses the `slice` object in Python, representing sequences of objects: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice

For numbers, you can just use the `range()` function: `list(range(1, 7))` returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` (it also supports steps).

Comment: This answer is interesting because it's in fact the direct implementation of OP's needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have icu4c and PyICU available, it is possible to construct a list of characters using Unicode sets:

```py
from icu import UnicodeSet
chars = list(UnicodeSet('[A-Z]'))
print(chars)  
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Using Unicode sets, a lot more sophisticated and complex sets can be developed. For instance, all uppercase Latin script letters:

`upper_latin = list(UnicodeSet('[[\p{Lu}] & [\p{Script=Latn}]]'))`

Comment: Very good answer because it can also provide locale characters (if needed). I actually tried to get my native language alphabet but failed to install `PyICU`. Here's the link for Windows users how to install `PyICU` as of 2024: https://github.com/cgohlke/pyicu-build

Comment: @SorenV.Raben to get the letters used by a specific language better to use `icu.LocaleData` and retrieve the main exemplars for the desired locale. See German example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637553/how-to-get-all-unicode-characters-of-a-language-by-using-its-iso-language-code-i/77165282#77165282